# Seeking thoughts on a weird error in printk.h

Tags: rhel, gcc, proprietary-drivers, compiler, linux-headers

I am compiling a vendor provided proprietary test code for their device driver on rhel8.4, kernel version 4.18.0-305.10.2.el8_4.x86_64. Both the driver and the corresponding test code had been originally released for testing and deployment on rhel6.6.

The compiler cribs about the following lines of code in the system header file `<linux/printk.h>`:

```
static inline __printf(1, 2) __cold
     void early_printk(const char *s, ...) { }
```

In accordance with the description provided in the following link for declaring the `format attribute` for functions

[Declaring Attributes of Functions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.2/gcc/Function-Attributes.html)

there is a corresponding declaration in the system header file `<linux/compiler-gcc.h>` as shown below:

```
#define __printf(a, b)          __attribute__((format(printf, a, b)))
```

The kernel forbids the direct inclusion of `<linux/compiler-gcc.h>` in source, and recommends indirect inclusion by means of `<linux/compiler.h>`.

The file `<linux/printk.h>` has been included in the system header file `<linux/kernel.h>`, after the inclusion of `<linux/compiler.h>`. The header file provided with the proprietary vendor code includes `<linux/kernel.h>`.

Based on the above, one would expect the compiler to find the expansion for the format attribute in the aforementioned declaration in `<linux/printk.h>`:

```
static inline __printf(1, 2) __cold
         void early_printk(const char *s, ...) { }
```

But instead, the compiler flags the format attribute as an error:

```
/usr/src/kernels/4.18.0-305.10.2.el8_4.x86_64/include/linux/printk.h:145:24: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before numeric constant
 static inline __printf(1, 2) __cold
```

The following is the sequence of kernel system file inclusions inside `<linux/kernel.h>`, leading up to the inclusion of `<linux/printk.h>`:

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <linux/limits.h>
#include <linux/linkage.h>
#include <linux/stddef.h>
#include <linux/types.h>
#include <linux/compiler.h>
#include <linux/bitops.h>
#include <linux/log2.h>
#include <linux/typecheck.h>
#include <linux/printk.h>
```

I am using gcc version 8.4.1 20200928.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: Doesn’t the vendor have an updated version for RHEL 8?

Comment: @StephenKitt Unfortunately NO